# CaseShare - INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY

Tags: apex

Trying to add Users with Customer Community to CaseShare.  Getting  first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id.  I have my assumptions but I need confirmation before I go back to the client.  I am adding users that associated to Contacts for the same Account that the User(Contact) is associated to in a Trigger on Insert...  The following is the code.

Controller has without sharing set.

List conList = new List();
        List contList = new List();
        List accList = new List();
        List accntList = new List();
        List caseList = new List();
        Map uList = new Map();

```
    //Getting Account Ids from the triggered Case
     for(Case c : newObjectList) {
        accList.add(c.accountId);
    }

    // Getting the Accounts that have Record Type DC

    for(Account a : [SELECT id, RecordType.Name FROM Account WHERE id = :accList  AND RecordType.Name = 'DC']) {
        accntList.add(a.id);
    }

    // Processing only if there is any account with DC Record type

    if(accntList.size() > 0) {

        // Getting all the contacts that belong to the above accounts

        for(Contact c : [SELECT id, accountid, User_Id__c from Contact WHERE accountId = :accntList ]) {
            contList.add(c);
            uList.put(c.Id,c.User_Id__c);
        }

        // Removing the contact id who had created the case

        for(case c : newObjectList) {
            for(Integer i = 0; i < contList.size();i++) {

                if(!contlist[i].id.equals(c.contactid)) {
                    conList.add(contList[i]);

                }
            }

        }

        // Getting the UserId for the contacts with whom the case has to be shared
        // only if there is any contact

        if(conList.size()>0){

            // Sharing the case with the contacts of respective accounts

            for(Case c : newObjectList) {

                for(Integer i =0; i < conList.size(); i++) {
                    if(c.accountid.equals(conList[i].accountid) && uList.containsKey(conList[i].Id)) {


                        if(uList.get(conList[i].Id) != UserInfo.getUserId() || string.valueOf(c.CreatedBy) != string.valueOf(uList.get(conList[i].Id ))){
                            CaseShare cs = new CaseShare();
                            cs.CaseAccessLevel = 'Edit';
                            cs.CaseId = c.Id;
                            cs.UserOrGroupId =  uList.get(conList[i].Id);
                            caseList.add(cs);

                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            if (!caseList.isEmpty())
                insert caseList;

        }
    }
```

Comment: This can happen when you try to give access to a record to a user that already has access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar problem getting the same error message as described above, first let me explain my case:

I have a visual force page with an extension "without sharing" that list cases that the current logged in customer community user has not access to.

I use a apex:dataTable with this column:

```
<apex:column>
  <apex:commandLink value="{!c.CaseNumber}" action="{!SetCaseSharing}">
    <apex:param name="setCaseSharing" value="{!c.Id}" assignTo="{!caseIdSelected}"/>
  </apex:commandLink>
</apex:column>
```

When the user selects a case clicking on the commandLink this method runs (a bit simplified):

```
public Id caseIdSelected {get; set;}

public SetCaseSharing()
{
  Case c = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id = :caseIdSelected];
  CaseShare caseShare = new CaseShare();
  caseShare.CaseId = c.Id;
  caseShare.UserOrGroupId = UserInfo.getUserId();
  caseShare.RowCause = 'Manual';
  caseShare.CaseAccessLevel = 'Edit';
  upsert(caseShare);
}
```

I know about the limitation that the current record owner cannot be added using manual apex sharing, and you cannot limit the access granted using sharing rules only add permission. These issues are not the problem in my case.

When logging in as a customer commmunity user using "Manage External Users" and then select a case from the list the problem occurs.

My code worked perfectly however when logging into the community as an administrator or "normal" user (instead of customer community user) and then adding a "normal" user (not a customer community user) to the manual sharing.

**PROBLEM 1**

I was not allowed to set manual sharing to a customer community user, even logged in as administrator, returning:

> Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: unknown (invalid user or group: 00511000002Hgs3): [unknown]

I guess the first problem might be solved using the more expensive "partner community license" or "customer community plus license" instead of "customer community license".

**PROBLEM 2**

I was not allowed to set manual sharing to a "normal" user when logged in as a customer community user, returning:

> Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

Not sure if it is possible to add sharing rules from the community when the logged in user is a customer community user not having access to the case in the first place. Moving this to a trigger or a scheduled job running separate from the community might solve it.